# Mysqli: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: mysqli, php

Добрый день! Друзья, подскажите, почему появляется ошибка:

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in ... on line 16`

Сам код:

```
$mysqli   = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$resultat = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * From profiles WHERE username = ?');
$resultat->bind_param('s', $profiles);
$profiles = "profiles";
$epp      = $resultat->execute();
$fetched  = $epp->fetch();

/* Выборка результатов запроса */
print_r($fetched);

/* Освобождаем используемую память */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: и в какая строка 16я ?

Comment: $fetched  = $epp->fetch();

Comment: Что ни кто не знает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте или есть таблица `profiles` в базе `test`
2. Вот это нужно поменять местами:

   ```
   $resultat->bind_param('s', $profiles);
   $profiles = "profiles";
   ```

что бы было вот так:

```
$profiles = "profiles";
$resultat->bind_param('s', $profiles);
```

> > $fetched = $epp->fetch();

ну правильно, нужно вот так:

```
$resultat->execute();
$fetched  = $resultat->fetch();
```

Comment: Возвращает 1, а нужно что бы был массив с данными.

Comment: Пробивал изменить так:
$fetched  = $resultat->fetch_assoc();
Появилась новая ошибка:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()